# Is the expected distance of two random variables a Metric?

Tags: distributions, expected-value, metric, distance-functions

This is purely for more understanding and not an assignment.

I understand the definition of a metric https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics). I also understand that the following is a metric in random variables
\begin{align}
y = \mathbb{E}(||x_1-x_2||)
\end{align}
What I am unsure of is if the following are metrices.
\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}(||x_1-x_2||^2) \\ \text{and}   
(\mathbb{E}||x_1-x_2||)^2
\end{align}
I understand the first one has a closed-form expression for the gaussian distribution
Also, I am assuming $\mathbb{E}(||x_1-x_2||^2)$ is a square of y and that $y^2$ would be a metric.
Would this be correct? And how can I show that $y^2$ is a metric (Hint is fine)?

Comment: In the Wikipedia link you provided, there are [three axioms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Definition) that describe what a metric is. Prove that these three axioms are true for your function of interest and you will have proven that it is a metric.

Comment: Your first equation has $y$ on both sides. I expect you want some other symbol to the left of the "$=$", perhaps $d$ for example.

Comment: Almost always, the hardest part of demonstrating a function is a metric is establishing the triangle inequality.  For that you need the [Minkowski Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) or its equivalent.  BTW, the first is not a metric for random variables: it is only a metric for equivalence classes of almost surely equal variables.  (It fails on the first axiom: the expected norm of two non-identical variables can be zero.)

Comment: @whuber are you saying then that y is not a metric or the first expression below it?